# passing Tensor objects of different shapes to tf.train.batch

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am executing this operation:

```
images, labels, labels2 = tf.train.batch([image, lbl1, lbl2], batch_size=32);
```

where `image`, `lbl1`, and `lbl2` are of type `Tensor` and `Dimension(None)`.

`image` is a 3-D matrix. `lbl1` and `lb2` will represent float arrays.

The problem is, these are all of different sizes,  and `tf.train.batch` requires that the `Tensor` objects are of a defined shape.  So, of course, I get an error like the one below:

```
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]
```

How can I do this if there are certain images and labels of different sizes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow: batches of variable-sized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147525/tensorflow-batches-of-variable-sized-images)

Comment: Looks like you posted the same question twice?

Comment: Yes, this was the first,and I did not get a response. I posted a second (the duplicate you cited) and got a response there. Once I got a response there, I answered this question. Should I delete?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `dynamic_pad` to `True` allows dimensions of shape `None`.

```
images, labels, labels2 = tf.train.batch([image, lbl1, lbl2], batch_size=32, dynamic_pad=True);
```