# tensorflow: batches of variable-sized images

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

When one passes to tf.train.batch, it looks like the shape of the element has to be strictly defined, else it would complain that `All shapes must be fully defined` if there exist Tensors with shape `Dimension(None)`. How, then, does one train on images of different sizes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set `dynamic_pad=True` in the argument of [`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch).

> `dynamic_pad`: Boolean. Allow variable dimensions in input shapes. The given dimensions are padded upon dequeue so that tensors within a batch have the same shapes.

Comment: Well. That worked. Ya know, I've been searching around for 3 days for an answer like that. :D

Comment: `tf.train.batch` is deprecated. Use `tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch` instead: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch

Answer (score 1):

Usually, images are resized to a certain number of pixels.

Depending on your task you might be able to use other techniques in order to process images of varying sizes. For example, for face recognition and OCR, a fix sized window is used, that is then moved over the image. On other tasks, convolutional neural networks with pooling layers or recurrent neural networks can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is quite old question, but in case someone will be searching how variable-size images can be still used in batches, I can tell what I did for Image-to-Image convolutional network (inference), which was trained for variable image size and batch 1. **Why**: when I tried to process images in batches using padding, the results become much worse, because signal was "spreading" inside of the network and started to influence its convolution pyramids.

So what I did is possible when you have source code and can load weights manually into convolutional layers. I modified the network in the following way: along with a batch of zero-padded images, I added additional placeholder which received a batch of binary masks with 1 where actual data was on the patch, and 0 where padding was applied. Then I multiplied signal by these masks **after each convolutional layer** inside the network, fighting "spreading". Multiplication isn't expensive operation, so it did not affect performance much.

The result was not deformed already, but still had some border artifacts, so I modified this approach further by adding small (2px) symmetric padding around input images (kernel size of all the layers of my CNN was 3), and kept it during propagation by using slightly bigger (+[2px,2px]) mask.

One can apply the same approach for training as well. Then some sort of "masked" loss is needed, where only the ROI on each patch is used to calculate loss. For example, for L1/L2 loss you can calculate the difference image between generated and label images and apply masks before summing up. More complicated losses might involve unstacking or iterating batch, and extracting ROI using `tf.where` or `tf.boolean_mask`.

Such training can be indeed beneficial in some cases, because you can combine small and big inputs for the network without small inputs being affected by the loss of big padded surroundings.